# character corruption in foreach in blade Laravel

Tags: laravel

What should I do to fix this problem?

to output all data in foreach.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $workSchedules =  DB::table('schedules')
        ->join('posts', 'schedules.work_id', '=', 'posts.user_id')->
        leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'worker_schedules.work_id')->
        get();
        Log::debug($Schedules);
        return view('index', ['posts' => $Schedules ]);
    }
```

Result:

[{"worker_id":4,"name":"\u304a\","title":"\u304a\u3063\u3068\u3063\u3068","body":"\u5bfe\u9593","cost":2000,"available":"1,2,3,4"},{"worker_id":6,"name":"\u304a\","title":"\u304a\u3063\u3068\u3063\u3068\","body":"\u5bfe\u9593","cost":2200,"available":"1,2,3,4"}]

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? `{{$article->available_time}}
{{$article->scheduled_date}}` because you haven't `select()`ed them?

Comment: What is the meaning of select()?  I would like to know about why the second element don't come out in foreach.

Comment: Thank you... kerbh0lz I overlooked a problem and settled this question.